# Настройка SFML с нуля

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-studio-2022

Начал изучать GUI для C++. Решил остановиться на SFML. В разных инструкциях из интернета начал настраивать среду разработки, но я столкнулся с проблемой одной - нигде нет файла jpeg.lib, из-за чего мое изучение на этом и остановилось, так и не успев начаться.

Можете подсказать как настроить среду разработки правильно или же где найти данный файл?

Comment: Его стоит сделать самому, собрав соответствующую библиотеку.

Comment: @user7860670 из чего собрать хоть?

Comment: Из соответствующей библиотеки.

Comment: @user7860670 из какой библиотеки-то?

Comment: Это вам надо выяснить самостоятельно, ознакомившись с документацией и проектом sfml

Comment: @user7860670 я бы не стал просить о помощи, если бы не изучил тему перед этим сам

Comment: *"изучил тему перед этим сам"* - видимо не изучили, во всяком случае, никаких подтверждений этого вы не привели. На [странице с оф гайдом по работе с SFML в Visual Studio](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php) никаких упоминаний о необходимости jpeg.lib нет. С чего она вам понадобилась - написать в вопросе вы не удосужились.

Comment: @user7860670, зачем собирать, если есть готовый?

Comment: @OtetsValerian, вы наверное статические библиотеки используете вместо динамических, надо использовать те где нет `-s`